# SQL запрос с использованием JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Даны две таблицы со столбцами

**AUTHORS**

-AUTHOR_ID (PK)

-AUTHOR_NAME

**BOOKS**

-BOOK_ID (PK)

-AUTHOR_ID (FK)

-BOOK_NAME

Задача:
Выбрать имена всех авторов, у которых более 10 книг.

Заранее спасибо.
PS Буду благодарен за ссылку на объяснение джойнов для самых тупых (все, что нашел сам, не помогло понять)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- выбрать имена авторов
SELECT a.author_name
-- из таблиц авторов и книг
FROM authors a, books b
-- где идентификатор автора совпадает с идентификатором автора книги
WHERE a.author_id = b.author_id
-- причём для данного автора
GROUP BY a.author_name
-- количество (уникальных) идентификаторов книг больше 10
HAVING COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ b.book_id) > 10
```

Если непременно нужен JOIN, то

```
-- выбрать имена авторов
SELECT a.author_name
-- из таблиц авторов и книг
FROM authors a INNER JOIN books b
-- где идентификатор автора совпадает с идентификатором автора книги
ON a.author_id = b.author_id
-- причём для данного автора
GROUP BY a.author_name
-- количество (уникальных) идентификаторов книг больше 10
HAVING COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ b.book_id) > 10
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы могли бы вкратце сказать про "а" и "b"? Я так понял, это алиасы, но зачем именно они нужны, и будет ли запрос функционировать без них? В чем удобство? Или это просто "хороший тон"?

Comment: В данном случае алиасы излишни, можно было использовать и имена таблиц. Правда, алиасы короче... а вот когда в запросе нужно использовать несколько копий одной таблицы, или когда есть подзапросы-таблицы - без алиасов никуда, без них серверу не понять, откуда, из какой именно таблицы, надо брать поле из нескольких одноимённых.

Comment: Понял, значит стоит ознакомиться, как минимум:) Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT AUTHORS.AUTHOR_NAME FROM AUTHORS 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID AS AID, COUNT(*) AS BOOKCOUNT FROM
    AUTHORS INNER JOIN BOOKS ON AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = BOOKS.AUTHOR_ID
    GROUP BY AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID
) ON AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = AID WHERE BOOKCOUNT > 10;
```

Применяемый здесь INNER JOIN работает так: он формирует из двух таблиц одну, кортежи которой "слеплены" из атрибутов обоих таблиц, однако для "слепки" выбираются лишь те кортежи, для которых выполняется условие после ON.